# I want to configure AWS S3 on my django project but many of my client's media files are on my pythonanywhere server already

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, media

I want to integrate AWS S3 in my django project and i have successfully integrated that but the problem is many of my client's media files are already on the pythonanywhere server and now i want to change it to AWS S3 so the upcoming media files should be stored in S3. But now what happens is that the new files are storing correctly and i can open them but the previous files, when i open them because of the media files url i suppose django looks it in AWS S3 but they are not there. So i need django to understand to look for the media files where they are stored like for the previous files i want django to look in the server directory and for new files in S3 instance.

Hope that makes sense.

[This is my AWS S3 configurations file for my django project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FS3jw.png)

[This is my django settings file, mainly focuses on media files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UIs7.png)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to move your static files that were uploaded before you configured AWS S3 with django you can run this command in your command line: `python manage.py collectstatic`.